# How to append multiple DOM elements to an element created with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I've just started work with reactjs and have not done much hands-on work with it. So far I'm able to create DOM elements through reactjs using JSXTransformer.js. The problem I'm getting is, when I try to create multiple elements within a DOM element, it *replaces* the old elements with the new ones.

That is, if I want to create `div_B`, `div_C` and `div_D` in `mainDiv`, it just adds `div_D` in the `mainDiv` because it is create last. But I want to append all three divs in the `mainDiv`.

The code I'm using is following:

```js
var props = [];
function getEle(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function setProps(ele, Css, inner, id) {
    props.element = ele;
    props.CssClass = Css;
    props.innerText = inner;
    props.id = id;
    return props;
}
function createElement(properties , element){
    var CreateDiv = React.createClass({
        render : function(){
            return <div className = {this.props.elementProps.CssClass} id={this.props.elementProps.id}>{this.props.innerText}</div>;
        }
    });
    React.render(<CreateDiv elementProps = {properties} />, element);
}

setProps("div", "divBClass", "", "div_B");
createElement(props, getEle("mainDiv"));

setProps("div", "divCClass", "", "div_C");
createElement(props, getEle("mainDiv"));

setProps("div", "divDClass", "", "div_D");
createElement(props, getEle("mainDiv"));
```

Is there anything wrong with that code?

Comment: Why not just declare 3 divs?  I can't really wrap my head around what you are attempting.  You need a root element, and then just map a list and create more divs.

Comment: @DavinTryon I want to append DOM elements in my mainDiv, but everytime I add an element, it replaces it, I'm asking how to append multiple elements in a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still thinking about your code in an imperative manner. React is based on a declarative programming paradigm.

First, think about your whole application as a React component.

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>foo</div>
    );
  }
})

React.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Now, let's first render some paragraphs:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // construct array [0, 1, 2]
    var values = [];
    for (var i=0; i<this.props.noDivs; i++) {
      values.push(i);
    }

    // return <p>0</p> <p>1</p> ...
    return (
      <div>
      {values.map(function (value) {
        return <p key={value}>Value {value}</p>;
      })}
      </div>
    );
  }
})

React.render(<App noDivs={3} />, document.body);
```

If JSX is too much, try to compile it [to Javascript](http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html). [Here](https://jsbin.com/taqoba/edit?js,output) is a live example. I'm passing the number of paragraphs as a prop.

Comment: Thanks @Alex your answer is really helpful for a person like me who is just getting started with react. I was not aware (or perhaps I missed it) to use this map function for rendering multiple items. +1